# How to make button desappear in Unity?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, button

How can I let the red button "start new game" disappear when something got saved over prefabs.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Savescene : MonoBehaviour
{
   public void save()
    {
        if (!File.Exists("saved.txt"))
        {
            File.Create("saved.txt");
        }
        else
        {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("saved.txt");
        sw.WriteLine("True");
        sw.Close();
        }
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SceneSaved", SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SceneSaved"));
    }
}
```

Buttons

[image]

Related code

[image]

Comment: There is no attachment.

Comment: I have added the pictures with a link

Comment: Thanks for edit ( I am bad in englisch)

Comment: @Lomusire yes ^^ But to your question: In general don't post images of code! Please rather copy&paste your code into the question and format it via the `{ }` button. Then usually you "disable" stuff using `someGameObject.SetActive(true);` so you could read out the `PlayerPrefs` and disable the button if it is not the default value e.g. `var scene = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SceneSaved", -1); button.gameObject.SetActive(scene == -1);`

Comment: @derHugo danke dir vielmals, aber ich kann leider noch kaum english, drum verstehe ich deine Antwort nicht so ganz....ich werde in Zukunft den Code als Text einfügen statt als  Bild. Danke für den Tipp! Ich bin erst vor 2 Wochen in Unity eingetaucht.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of english is not my native language, I cannot completely understand this phrase: `when something got saved over prefabs` in your question. But as I understand you need to make button disappear when something a game have already been started? You can write some info in PlayerPrefs, like this:
`PlayerPrefs.SetInt("showStartNewGameButton", -1) // or any other number except of 0`
And then you can check, if "showStartNewGameButton" equals to 0 (it is default value), the button must be shown, otherwise is doesn't.

The disappearing itself may be implemented by deactivating of the object this way:
`button.gameObject.SetActive(false); // if you do want to show the button, you must it's true, not false`